# How to output an html file in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to know how to output in the screen an html file. I have a route function and i want to display html to a website

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return "hi"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow!

To render an html template in flask first you must create a folder named `templates`. The folder must be in the same directory as your main file (where the app runs)

Then create a html file in the templates folder. You can call it whatever you want, I will call it index.html

Then add this code to your route:

```
from Flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, hope this helps!

```py
import Flask
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return flask.send_from_directory(".", path="index.html")
```

Comment: What are you doing here?

Comment: @OlauPla what???

Comment: You are not rendering an html template, i don't understand what you do in this code

Comment: This solution works and I use it? just read the documentation

Comment: If you read the documentation or in general read/watch videos or books the answer you will find is mine. I'm just asking why you use that instead of what I propose

Comment: They both are solutions for this, I just use this one, no particular reason it just works so I use it, not much else to it.